# Spark Druid Connector Error com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'root1234': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, druid

We are tying to connect Druid Deep Storage via Spark and found a repo [here](https://github.com/JulianJaffe/spark-druid-connector) that could help us but there was version mismatch so I had to make some changes to make it compatible with our environment which is;
`scala version : 2.11 spark version : 2.4.3`
and as we try to read from druid as specified in the repo like this;

```scala
    import com.julianjaffe.spark_druid_connector.DruidDataFrameReader
    import com.julianjaffe.spark_druid_connector.model.HdfsDeepStorageConfig
    
    val deepStorageConfig = new HdfsDeepStorageConfig().storageDirectory("oss://debucket/druid/segments")
    spark.read
         .brokerHost("10.100.1.123")
         .brokerPort(18082)
         .metadataDbType("mysql")
         .metadataUri("jdbc:mysql://10.100.1.123:3306/druid")
         .metadataUser("root")
         .metadataPassword("root1234")
         .dataSource("interaction")
         .deepStorage(deepStorageConfig)
         .druid()`
```

throws an error:

> Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'root1234': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')

We have also tried the way below but no luck :(

```
val properties = Map[String, String](
  "metadata.dbType" -> "mysql",
  "metadata.connectUri" -> "jdbc:mysql://10.100.1.123:3306/druid",
  "metadata.user" -> "root",
  "metadata.password" -> "root123",
  "broker.host" -> "10.100.1.123",
  "broker.port" -> "8082",
  "table" -> "dataSource",
  "reader.deepStorageType" -> "hdfs",
  "local.storageDirectory" -> "oss://debucket/druid/segments/")

spark
  .read
  .format("druid")
  .options(properties)
  .load()
```

Comment: Look's like `metadata.password` must be a Boolean value.

Comment: but how could it be it is designed to contain a password :(

Comment: `def metadataPassword(password: String): DataFrameReader = reader.option(metadataPrefix(DruidConfigurationKeys.metadataPasswordKey), password)`